Equalize values of a list of list
It's not easy for me to search for similar questions, I guess because the term "equalize" is not correct.

Scenario
I have a couple of list of lists, not actually a matrix since each list can be of different length.
Let's see an example.
The first list-of-lists data set contains the id of each item (actually, they are the primary key field of a database table):
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['b', 'e', 'f', 'g']
['h', 'i', 'j']
['b', 'i', 'k', 'l']

as you can see, each list may have different length, the id can be in one or more lists, but they can appear at most once in the same list.
Then, I have the twin list-of-lists data set, with the same dimensions:
[3.2, 3.2, 5.1, 6.8, 1.7] # -> sum: 20.0
[2.8, 6.7, 8.4, 2.1]      # -> sum: 20.0
[9.7, 7.3, 3.0]           # -> sum: 20.0
[4.3, 1.8, 8.7, 5.2]      # -> sum: 20.0

Each list has the same sum: 20.0 in this example.
Now I sum the values associated to the same id:
'a' -> 3.2
'b' -> 3.2 + 2.8 + 4.3 = 10.3
'c' -> 5.1
'd' -> 6.8
'e' -> 1.7 + 6.7 = 8.4
'f' -> 8.4
'g' -> 2.1
'h' -> 9.7
'i' -> 7.3 + 1.8 = 9.1
'j' -> 3.0
'k' -> 8.7
'l' -> 5.2

I also have a separate list with all the above id where to store their sum.
Problem
The goal is to try as much as possible to "equalize" the values of each id (in other words trying to make them as equal as possible) keeping the sum of each list to the same value (20.0 in the given example).
[Note: this is not an exercize, I tried to simplify it as I could, but it's a real-case scenario. I'm trying to set up the cleaning shifts for the school of my daughter]
Expected output
I cannot show the actual solution of the problem, otherwise I'll already solved it and I've not posted this question.
Anyway, I'm expecting to have the same sum for each list (20.0 in this example) and the sum of each id as equal as possible to each other. Ideally, they should be equal to each other, let's say:
'a' -> x
'b' -> x
'c' -> x
'd' -> x
'e' -> x
'f' -> x
'g' -> x
'h' -> x
'i' -> x
'j' -> x
'k' -> x
'l' -> x

where x = 20.0 / 12 (12 is the number of the id)
Some code
lista_classi = [] # contains the name of the lists (4 in our example)
lista_famiglie = [] # contains all the id
lista_famiglie_turni = [] # will contain the sum associated to each id
matrix_famiglie_classi = [] # list of lists that contains the id(first table above)
matrix_famiglie = [] # list of lists that contains the values, this is actually a matrix, with all the rows: if an id is not present its value is 0

NUMERO_TURNI = 20.0 # the constant sum
conn = pymysql.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Password, database='school') 
cursor = conn.cursor() 
   
# Retrieve the list of all id
sql = "SELECT id FROM anagrafica_famiglie;"
cursor.execute(sql)
lista_famiglie = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
lista_famiglie_turni = [None] * len(lista_famiglie)

# Retrieve the number (and the name, not important here) of each list
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT classe FROM anagrafica_alunni ORDER BY classe;"
cursor.execute(sql)
lista_classi = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()] 

# For each list...
for c in lista_classi:
    # ...retrieve the id that belong to the list
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT anagrafica_famiglie.id FROM anagrafica_famiglie INNER JOIN anagrafica_alunni ON anagrafica_famiglie.famiglia = anagrafica_alunni.famiglia WHERE anagrafica_famiglie.esonero=0 AND anagrafica_alunni.classe='{}';".format(c)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    matrix_famiglie_classi.append(result)
    
    # ...and the rectangular matrix with all the id (to simplify the indexing)    
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT anagrafica_famiglie.id FROM anagrafica_famiglie INNER JOIN anagrafica_alunni ON anagrafica_famiglie.famiglia = anagrafica_alunni.famiglia WHERE anagrafica_famiglie.esonero=0"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    matrix_famiglie.append(result)

for i in range(len(lista_classi)):
    print(lista_classi[i].ljust(10) + "{}".format(len(matrix_famiglie_classi[i])))

# Calculate the initial values (as the above example)
for i in range(len(lista_classi)):
    for j in range(len(lista_famiglie)):
        if lista_famiglie[j] in matrix_famiglie_classi[i]:
            matrix_famiglie[i][j] = NUMERO_TURNI / len(matrix_famiglie_classi[i])
        else:
            matrix_famiglie[i][j] = 0

now a couple of functions to retrieve the maximum and the minimum value(s) across all the id
def getMaxShift():
    return [index for index, item in enumerate(lista_famiglie_turni) if item == max(lista_famiglie_turni)], max(lista_famiglie_turni)

def getMinShift():
    return [index for index, item in enumerate(lista_famiglie_turni) if item == min(lista_famiglie_turni)], min(lista_famiglie_turni)

What I've tried
My first attempt was like this:

calculate the sum of values for each id (done, I guess)
find the maximum value(s) and the minimum one(s) (done, I guess)

from this point ahead it's just a blind guess

for each list, check if it contains one or more id included in the maximum or minimum list
if found, decrease or increase their values
adjust (how!?) the other values on the list to keep the sum constant
repeat the process from point 1. until it will "converge", i.e. the difference between the maximum and minimum sum of any id cannot be smaller

Quesions

is my algorithm correct?
if yes, I'm not able to code the point 5: I know the sum, I fixed some values, but how to change the others?


I tried to solve it manually in this way:
id  sum     ideal   sum / ideal
a   3.20    6.67    0.48
b   10.30   6.67    1.55
c   5.10    6.67    0.77
d   6.80    6.67    1.02
e   8.40    6.67    1.26
f   8.40    6.67    1.26
g   2.10    6.67    0.32
h   9.70    6.67    1.46
i   9.10    6.67    1.37
j   3.00    6.67    0.45
k   8.70    6.67    1.31
l   5.20    6.67    0.78

where ideal = 20.0 * 4 / 12 (size of id).
Then I divided each value by the last column of the table above:
6.67    2.07    6.67    6.67    1.35    # sum 23.42
1.81    5.32    6.67    6.67            # sum 20.46
6.67    5.35    6.67                    # sum 18.68
2.78    1.32    6.67    6.67            # sum 17.44

that leads to:
a   6.67
b   6.67
c   6.67
d   6.67
e   7.02
f   6.67
g   6.67
h   6.67
i   6.67
j   6.67
k   6.67
l   6.67

that's very close to the solution from the id point of view (I bet I did some calculation error for e), but the sums of each list are wrong.
What am I doing wrong?
I've asked a related question also on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4956096/evenly-distribute-shifts-among-persons-who-belongs-to-multiple-rooms

Please, given the inputs, show the expected 'equalized' output !, that'll help minimise (mis)interpretation/ambiguties (edit your submission)

@ticktalk the expected output is the sum for each list to be 20.0 and the sum for each id as equal as possible. Showing the actual result would mean I've already solved the algorithm, so no need for this question

@ticktalk I've update the question with a paragraph about the expected output

"I cannot show the actual solution of the problem, otherwise I'll already solved it and I've not posted this question." you can solve it by hand and your question is how to write code that solves it. If it's too difficult to solve by hand, find an easier example.

I have the feeling that what you mean by "equalize" is some kind of Knapsack problem.

@mkrieger1 I tried to solved it manually, but I failed (question updated). I've already tried with a simpler example, but the problem is there a trivial solution hides the real-case issues, I'm afraid

I'd try a simple randomized hill-climbing, selecting two indices at random in the same list, and increasing/decreasing them by the same value (thus keeping the sum constant), then seeig if it's better than before, and repeat...

@tobias_k in which way should it be better than selecting the max and min values as I proposed? Should not be faster than selecting they at random?

@Mark I did not read your code in detail, but your approach sounded like "greedy", which probably is faster, but might miss the optimal solution. The randomized approach should (maybe after a few random restarts) get to a near-optimal solution. I haven't tried it on this particular problem, though.

@nocomment I tried to cut down the whole code to a minimal example as always is requested here. The data is actually fetched from the database, for this reason there is no data hardcoded. I left there to show the SQL query and the actual fields I fetch

@nocomment but without showing the SQL query, I'm not sure if it will be easy to understand what the code does

Considering the scale and kind of data you actually have to process, I wonder if you really need to use such a complex optimization approach instead of a brute force approach.

(Everyone can search, the craft is in finding something of value. Terms to try: unify, homogenise, level, distribute evenly.)

This looks like an optimization problem that you could solve with scipy.optimize.minimize. Here let's use numpy.std as the function to minimize (we want all values close to each other) and as constraints the individual sums of the different sets of variables to be equal to 20.
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# input keys/data
keys = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        ['b', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        ['h', 'i', 'j'],
        ['b', 'i', 'k', 'l'],
       ]

data = [[3.2, 3.2, 5.1, 6.8, 1.7], # -> sum: 20.0
        [2.8, 6.7, 8.4, 2.1],      # -> sum: 20.0
        [9.7, 7.3, 3.0],           # -> sum: 20.0
        [4.3, 1.8, 8.7, 5.2],
       ]

# get all params, order, and initial values
params = sorted(set().union(*keys))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
order = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(params)}
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11}
values = dict(zip(chain.from_iterable(keys),
                  chain.from_iterable(data)))
# {'a': 3.2, 'b': 4.3, 'c': 5.1, 'd': 6.8, 'e': 6.7, 'f': 8.4, 'g': 2.1, 'h': 9.7, 'i': 1.8, 'j': 3.0, 'k': 8.7, 'l': 5.2}

# compute parameters to pass to scipy.optimize.minimize
# min/max for each variable / initial guess / constraints
bounds = [(0, 20) for k in params]
# [(0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20)]
guess = [values[k] for k in params]
# [3.2, 4.3, 5.1, 6.8, 6.7, 8.4, 2.1, 9.7, 1.8, 3.0, 8.7, 5.2]
constraints = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': (lambda x, lst=lst: sum(x[order[k]] for k in lst) - 20)}
               for lst in keys]

# perform optimization
res = minimize(np.std, x0=guess, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

# get optimized values as dictionary
out = dict(zip(params, res.x))

# check sums
[sum(out[k] for k in lst) for lst in keys]
# [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0]

Output:
{'a': 3.811479205180912,
 'b': 4.109617661067273,
 'c': 3.8115530506109474,
 'd': 3.8116192300490845,
 'e': 4.455730853091784,
 'f': 5.717448271344535,
 'g': 5.717203214496409,
 'h': 6.782195915236723,
 'i': 6.435868903030428,
 'j': 6.781935181732849,
 'k': 4.7273246860121665,
 'l': 4.72718874989013}

There is always a possibility that this solution is not the best one (the optimization could fail), but here we decreased the standard deviation from the initial guess:
np.std(guess)
# 2.546511775394377

np.std(list(out.values()))
# 1.1124854618799502


Thanks for the hint! If I understand correctly, I can repeat the process many times to improve the optimization further?

@Mark I don't think you can repeat the process, if you provide the output of a successful optimization as input guess, then there won't be any further optimization since the guess is already a valid solution.

Ok, but there is too much difference between the sum of 'a' and, say, 'h' - it's almost the double! Is there a way to prove there is no way to reduce it further? Just to understand, it's not a criticism!

There is not a general way to prove further optimization is not possible. There might be a specific way for your use case but this would be out of the scope of SO (you could ask this on math.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com). Are the constraint on the sum strict? Or could you allow some tolerance (like a bit below or above 20)?

Regarding the difference between a and h, keep in mind that there might not be a better solution. Imagine [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']] as example, there is no way you can get a "good" solution.

Thanks. I've already asked on math.stackexchange.com, I'm waiting an answer. Yes, the constraint on the sum it mandatory since it's the number of the weekends when the rooms have to be cleaned! It's acceptable a small difference in sums for each id (and it's expected!) but in the example: 'a' will clean the room 3 times, 'h' 6 times

OK you might want to add a link to the math question in your question here. Also, if the values are integers, this should be specified as this will change the optimization.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4956096/evenly-distribute-shifts-among-persons-who-belongs-to-multiple-rooms

I tried to make this question as close as possible for SO

@Mark the problem as you state it here seems different from the one you describe in math. Here you add an additional constraint that a given person should clean all their rooms the same time, which is not a necessary constraint and makes the problem much harder to solve.

With "the goal is to make equal numbers of shifts for all people" I meant "a given person should clean all their rooms the same time", I didn't change the constraint. Here I put the problem in floating point, there as integer, but the goal is the same
